# finding memory leaks in a boost::test::unit_test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, boost-test

This question is a [continuation to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219993/coinitializeex-for-a-boosttestunit-test) on boost::test::unit_test.

I've written a unit test and built the unit test.  Here's the build output:

```
    2>------ Build started: Project: UnitTests, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>  stdafx.cpp
2>  UnitTests.cpp
2>  UnitTests.vcxproj -> F:\Src\Crash\trunk\Debug\UnitTests.exe
2>  
2>  Running 3 test cases...
2>  Test suite "Master Test Suite" passed with:
2>    3 assertions out of 3 passed
2>    3 test cases out of 3 passed
2>  
2>  Detected memory leaks!
2>  Dumping objects ->
2>  {810} normal block at 0x007C5610, 8 bytes long.
2>   Data: <P C     > 50 E3 43 00 00 00 00 00 
2>  {809} normal block at 0x0043E350, 32 bytes long.
2>   Data: < V|             > 10 56 7C 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
2>  Object dump complete.
```

I know from experience that the output that describes the memory leak is from use of the [CRT memory leak detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Normally, to detect where the allocations are in source code, you might add the following to the start of your entry point:

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
_CrtSetBreakAlloc( 809 );
```

However, boost::test::unit_test defines its own entry point, preventing me from adding these lines.  I've tried adding these lines to a fixture, but without success.  I've also tried adding these lines inside the test code, again without success.  When I try these modifications, I get the following output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: UnitTests, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  UnitTests.cpp
1>  UnitTests.vcxproj -> F:\Src\Crash\trunk\Debug\UnitTests.exe
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: The command ""F:\Src\Crash\trunk\Debug\\UnitTests.exe" --result_code=no --report_level=short
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code -2147483645.
```

That -ve number translates to 0x80000003 (one or more arguments are invalid).

Can anyone suggest how I might detect where in my source code / tests these two memory leaks might be?

For the curious, here's my test:

```
void DShowUtilsGetFilter()
{
    // SysDevNames is a typedef for std::vector<wstring*>
    using namespace Crash::DirectShow;
    using namespace Crash::SystemDevices;
    using namespace std;

    _CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
    _CrtSetBreakAlloc( 809 );

    HRESULT                 hr  = S_OK; 
    SysDevNames             AudioDevices;
    wstring                 wsAudioDevice;  
    CComPtr <IBaseFilter>   spAudioFilter;

    try
    {
        TFAIL( ListDevicesInCategory( CLSID_AudioCompressorCategory, AudioDevices ) );

        if( AudioDevices.size() == 0 )
            throw E_FAIL;

        wsAudioDevice.assign(*AudioDevices.at(0));

        TFAIL( GetFilter( CLSID_AudioCompressorCategory, wsAudioDevice, &spAudioFilter ) );

        if( spAudioFilter.p )
            spAudioFilter.Release();

        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL (hr, S_OK);

    }
    catch(...)
    {
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( 1, 0 );              
    }


    if( AudioDevices.size() > 0)
    {
        for(SysDevNamesItr itr = AudioDevices.begin(); itr != AudioDevices.end(); itr ++ )
            delete *itr;

        AudioDevices.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/test/doc/html/execution-monitor/user-guide.html

You can probably set a command line argument to break at the required allocation ID.

Edit: use --detect_memory_leak  on the command line (from here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/reference.html )

Comment: this does appear to be the correct answer.  However, when I specify --detect_memory_leak=809, I get another crash with a very similar error as before.  I'll just put the program into a test harness and setup the CRT memory leak detection stuff myself to get to the bottom of this leak!  thanks!

Comment: Good luck. Hope you find the issue!